# Can't display data coming from service method into component

Tags: angular, http, service, angular5, injectable

Still working on my Angular 5 - PHP project.

I want to put all my http methods inside a single file called api, and call any method I want by just importing it into the desired component. I don't know if it's good to work like that or not.

Anyway, here is my `service` called `api.ts`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Api{
    public data: any = [];
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getPartnersName(){
        this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
        (response: Response) =>{
          this.data = response.json();
          console.log(this.data);
          //this.keys.push(this.data);
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    }
}
```

And I imported it in `app.module.ts`:

```
...//imports
...//Other imports
import { Api } from '../api/api';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [Api],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then I injected it in my component:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private api: Api){

}
```

Which is here `api: Api`.

Now, I called the method that I want to use inside `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getPartnersName();
}
```

The problem is that is I am seeing the data at the console properly:

[image]

But can't display them on screen:

```
<div class="row center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let datas of data;">
      {{datas.partner_name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` is defined in the service, but you want it to use in the component. Actually you need to remove the `subscribe` part from the service's `http` call implementation and move it into the component.

***Service***

```
getPartnersName(){
    return this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php')
                    .map((response: Response) => response.json());      
}
```

***Component***

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getPartnersName().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Also one note, with Angular 4.3 and upper, *Http* is deprecated, you can read about *HttpClient*

Comment: What is the difference here between `.subscribe` and `.map` in this case ?

Comment: Subscribe is the end station of the stream - saying that way. Map just parses the json and pass the value into the next handler. So in the subscribe you get already passed response

Comment: if he have a model he can map to model. `get<hero>();`

Comment: Yes of course, HttpClient (the newer abstraction) also gives this capability and you can also omit the `map` part

Comment: I have an error on `.subscribe` saying: **Property subscribe does not exist on type void**

Comment: Sorry, you need to return the observable from the `getPartnersName`

Comment: Another one: `ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function`

Comment: Have you imported `map` function from `rxjs`?

Comment: I imported the `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`  but still can't see the data @SurenSrapyan

Comment: Debug your code, see if you actually get the `data` in the subscribe function. Maybe you don't get it

Comment: how to debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your data in the scope of your service. You need to return that data to the component, subscribe inside the component and store it on a local variable inside that component, please see below

*Service*

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Api{
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getPartnersName(){
        this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').map(
        (response: Response) =>{
          return response.json();
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    }
}
```

*Component*

```
public data: any;

ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getPartnersName().
        subscribe((returnData: any) => {
            this.data = returnData;
        });
}
```

*html*

```
<div class="row center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let datas of data;">
      {{datas.partner_name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular 5 contains HttpClient instead of Http, your service would look as follows using HttpClient

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Api{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

    getPartnersName(){
        return this.http.get<any>('http://aff.local/getPartners.php');
    }
}
```

Your error handling would then be done in the `subscribe` inside your component.